# Expand dataframe rows from dates

Tags: r

I have a dataset with information about participants, jobs, date start job and date finish job. I would like to add a row for each year working in each job. I received the following STATA code: `expand finish_time-start_time + 1`, but I am working with R and I don't see haow to do the same. Is it possible to reply it in R?

I add an example of the data I have.

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,3),
                   job = c(1,2,1,1),
                   start_time = seq(as.Date('2017-01-01'), as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = 'years'),
                   finish_time = seq(as.Date('2020-12-01'), as.Date('2023-12-01'), by = 'years'))
```

In that case I would have 4 rows for each original row:

| id | job | start_time | finish_time | expand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | '2017-01-01' | '2020-12-01' | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | '2017-01-01' | '2020-12-01' | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | '2017-01-01' | '2020-12-01' | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | '2017-01-01' | '2020-12-01' | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | '2018-01-01' | '2021-12-01' | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | '2018-01-01' | '2021-12-01' | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | '2018-01-01' | '2021-12-01' | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | '2018-01-01' | '2021-12-01' | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | '2019-01-01' | '2022-12-01' | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | '2019-01-01' | '2022-12-01' | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | '2019-01-01' | '2022-12-01' | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | '2019-01-01' | '2022-12-01' | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | '2020-01-01' | '2023-12-01' | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | '2020-01-01' | '2023-12-01' | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | '2020-01-01' | '2023-12-01' | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | '2020-01-01' | '2023-12-01' | 4 |

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  summarize(id, job, start_time, finish_time,
            date = seq(start_time, finish_time, by = "year"))
# # A tibble: 16 × 5
#       id   job start_time finish_time date      
#    <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <date>      <date>    
#  1     1     1 2017-01-01 2020-01-01  2017-01-01
#  2     1     1 2017-01-01 2020-01-01  2018-01-01
#  3     1     1 2017-01-01 2020-01-01  2019-01-01
#  4     1     1 2017-01-01 2020-01-01  2020-01-01
#  5     1     2 2018-01-01 2021-01-01  2018-01-01
#  6     1     2 2018-01-01 2021-01-01  2019-01-01
#  7     1     2 2018-01-01 2021-01-01  2020-01-01
#  8     1     2 2018-01-01 2021-01-01  2021-01-01
#  9     2     1 2019-01-01 2022-01-01  2019-01-01
# 10     2     1 2019-01-01 2022-01-01  2020-01-01
# 11     2     1 2019-01-01 2022-01-01  2021-01-01
# 12     2     1 2019-01-01 2022-01-01  2022-01-01
# 13     3     1 2020-01-01 2023-01-01  2020-01-01
# 14     3     1 2020-01-01 2023-01-01  2021-01-01
# 15     3     1 2020-01-01 2023-01-01  2022-01-01
# 16     3     1 2020-01-01 2023-01-01  2023-01-01
```

Comment: I have more than those 4 variables in the dataframe, would it work without having to enter all the variables names?

Comment: Sure: with `dplyr_1.1.0` or newer, one can do `data %>% rowwise() %>% summarize(pick(everything()), date = seq(start_time, finish_time, by = "year"))`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(newcol = list(seq(start_time, finish_time, by = "year"))) %>% 
  unnest(newcol)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 16 × 5
      id   job start_time finish_time newcol    
   <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <date>      <date>    
 1     1     1 2017-01-01 2020-01-01  2017-01-01
 2     1     1 2017-01-01 2020-01-01  2018-01-01
 3     1     1 2017-01-01 2020-01-01  2019-01-01
 4     1     1 2017-01-01 2020-01-01  2020-01-01
 5     1     2 2018-01-01 2021-01-01  2018-01-01
 6     1     2 2018-01-01 2021-01-01  2019-01-01
 7     1     2 2018-01-01 2021-01-01  2020-01-01
 8     1     2 2018-01-01 2021-01-01  2021-01-01
 9     2     1 2019-01-01 2022-01-01  2019-01-01
10     2     1 2019-01-01 2022-01-01  2020-01-01
11     2     1 2019-01-01 2022-01-01  2021-01-01
12     2     1 2019-01-01 2022-01-01  2022-01-01
13     3     1 2020-01-01 2023-01-01  2020-01-01
14     3     1 2020-01-01 2023-01-01  2021-01-01
15     3     1 2020-01-01 2023-01-01  2022-01-01
16     3     1 2020-01-01 2023-01-01  2023-01-01
```